# "No, I hadn't." vs "No, I didn't."

Tags: grammar

Which is correct option to the following & Why:

Did you have lunch at home yesterday?
(1) No, I haven't.
(2) No, I hadn't.
(3) No, I didn't.
(4) No, I don't.

Comment: The basic question is "Did you?" So the response should be "No I didn't" or "Yes I did."

Answer (score 3):

Simply put, the question starts with "Did you" so the answer should be "Yes I did" or "no I did not".

Did not abbreviates to "didn't", so option 3 would be correct.

Comment: Hi, I would ask you if the question could also be "have you had lunch at home yesterday?" and what's the difference with "did you have.." in this case. Thanks.

Comment: "have" implies that it's in the present, which is incorrect, so in this case you should use "did" because this is in the past ('yesterday').

Comment: and what the "had" stands for? it doesn't implies it's in the past as well? Thank you again :-)

Answer (score 3):

> Did you have lunch at home yesterday? (1) No, I haven't. (2) No, I hadn't. (3) No, I didn't. (4) No, I don't.

The relevant word in the question is *did*, and the corresponding word in the reply would be *didn't*. So 3. is correct.

In the US you might not always find consistency in this. There is this bit of dialogue from a TV cop show:

"Hey, buddy, got a light?"

"Yes, I do."

But the question in expanded form is *have you got...*, to which the reply should be *Yes, I have*, which is the shortened form of *Yes, I have got...*. But the second guy answers as if the first guy had said *do you have...?* The reason, I'd guess, comes down to a vague but erroneous belief that *have got* is not as correct as *do have*, and therefore he effectively corrects guy No.1's grammar. But the result when you expand it is, *Yes, I do got a light*. The bad grammar lies with guy No. 2, not guy No.1.

Sometimes someone will even correct his own grammar, as in this from another cop show: "You've got a hunch, don't you?"

Comment: Personal preference - don't use 'got'. It is a lazy word and there are much better alternatives.

Comment: I would like to refute the charges of inconsistency. In some U.S. dialects, the right answer to *"have you got"* is *"yes I do"*. The right answer to *"have you gotten"* is *"yes I have"*. We're consistent. Maybe bonkers from your point of view, but consistent. This is because in these dialects, *"have"* is generally not treated as an auxiliary verb in *"have got"*, but only in *"have gotten"*.

Comment: What's this "we" you're talking about? I've never come across any American except you who thinks the *have* in *have got* isn't an auxiliary verb.

Comment: Of course it's an auxiliary verb, but in some dialects it's ***not treated as one*** in the phrase *"have got"* for the purposes of deciding which auxiliary verb to use in answers and question tags. So some Americans who would never say *"I've bought a new car, don't I?"* will say *"I've got a new car, don't I?"*. You've observed this phenomenon in American cop shows, and while you interpret it as they're correcting each other, or themselves, I claim this is the way that grammar works in their dialect.